# OutOfMemory in Protege when classifying ontology with Pellet

Tags: out-of-memory, ontology, protege, pellet

I've trouble on parsing of my ontology with Pellet in Protoge.

I've loaded the SeDI ontology from http://bioportal.bioontology.org/ontologies/SEDI (submision 1.0) to Protege. When classifying this ontology with Pellet reasoner the progress bar remains stay on ca. 20% and ends with OutOfMemory error after a lot of time (many minutes). Classifying with other reasoners such as FaCT++ and HermiT succeeded and takes only few seconds.

Many thanks for any hint.

Igor.

Comment: This is probably something you'd need to ask about on the Pellet mailing list.  This doesn't sound like anything in particular that we can debug (though we might be able to reproduce).  Even though other reasoners can process it, it might be more than what Pellet can handle, who knows?

Comment: You are right. I'll ask there. Thank you for your comment.